# Using texindy within paths containing diacritics

Tags: unicode, xindy, folders

I wonder if it is possible to use `texindy` in project where the project path contains umlauts, e.g. `/Users/Tobi/Desktop/äbc/test/`. With this path I get an error message:

```
Tobis-Mac:test Tobi$ texindy test.idx
Opening logfile "/dev/null" (done)
Reading indexstyle...
Loading module "/var/folders/1n/d3h2l7zj14z39dbv4k9ng6_m0000gp/T/t9SopP1Rvv"...

Error in line 1:
(require "lang/general/latin9-lang.xdy")
ERROR: PARSE-NAMESTRING: syntax error in filename "/Users/Tobi/Desktop/äbc/test/" at position 21
```

While a path like `/Users/Tobi/Desktop/abc/test/`(`a` instead of `ä`) works fine. To reproduce the error you may put this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Test\index{Test}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

in a folder like `…/äbc/test/` and then run

```
pdflatex test.tex
texindy test.idx
```

I know that in the TeX world it is better to use only lowercase `a`–`z` filenames and I do respect this for all TeX related filenames an the first parent folder (`test/` in this example) but I can’t for higher parent folders (`äbc/` here) because these folds be names of clients that contain umlauts and I want to keep them. For TeX everything is fine that way but `texindy` seems to have a problem with umlauts anywhere in the path.

**Version info**

```
xindy release: 2.4
xindy script version: 1.16
xindy kernel version: 3.0
CLISP version 2.48 (2009-07-28) (built on richard-kochs-computer.local [10.0.1.2])
    architecture: X86_64
```

Comment: I see that `texindy` has a `--language` option. Is that relevant?

Comment: I don’t thinks so … this option is only relevant for the sorting (and encoding of the input file) but it has nothing to do with the paths to the files …

Comment: Too bad. Was worth a shot.

Comment: Sure :-) I found this: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-May/033427.html but there’s no solution …

Comment: while it's somewhat archaic and presumptuous, perhaps renaming the folders to use, for example, "ae" instead of an umlauted "a" would serve the purpose?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Sure … this would be a workaround for the problem but I don’t want to solve it this way ;-) ae ≠ ä! Another example are Users with umlauts (e.g. Jürgen) or accents (e.g. René) in their names. Then the user directory may contains these letters as well and replacing them is a bad workaround and no real solution in times of unicode … I guess you’d dislike to be written “babara” sounds (quite) equal and is understandable but not the same as “barbara” ;-)

Comment: @Tobi -- agreed it's not ideal, rather a copout, and "rene" is a stopper.  (as for "babara", that's actually what it turns out to be transliterated into japanese; i've got a name tag to prove it.)

Comment: I wrote a bug repot on xindy’s SF homepage …

Comment: On windows 7 with a perl from activestate there is no problem. Are you sure that you have the newest xindy?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: No I’m not, it’s the one shipped with TeX Live 2013 and my distribution is up to date (which is the frozen state) … I added the version info to my question.

Comment: Does anybody know, if there’s news about this? The bug is still open and obviously not fixed …