# Getting xindy to run from a directory with an umlaut in its path

Tags: miktex, xindy

I use a Windows 10 setup with MiKTeX and I am trying to use xindy for index generation (for use with tex4ebook and the [helpers4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht) package). The xindy script was installed at the following location:

```
C:\Users\Jürgen\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl
```

However, when I try to compile the files (via the Windows command console), the tex4ebook script breaks off with the following error message:

[image: xindy error]

Apparently, the xindy.pl script cannot cope with the Umlaut in my user name. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What happens if you try to run (in some test folder!) `perl "C:\Users\Jürgen\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl" --help`?

Comment: I (re)found this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184822/2388, which allowed me to run a test without changing my user account name: texindy fails for me as soon as a parent folder contains an umlaut. If fails both with texlive and with miktex. Where is your document located? Also in the user account? Can you move it to some folder without any non-ascii chars in the path and try again?

Comment: You can substitute your user folder to some other drive: "subst y: c:\Users\Jürgen". Then you change to the Y: drive and work there. (Under the assumption that Y: was free initially. Obviously another option would be to switch to a user with Umlaut in it. BTW I can feel your pain. Have a look at my last name to see how I solved the problem once and for all.

Comment: I sent a question to the texlive list about it https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-September/042369.html. But don't have to many hopes about a real solution.

Comment: Akira answered on the texlive list and says (what I already suspected) the quite probably xindy-lisp.exe can't handle files with Umlauts. So you should at least relocate your documents to a folder without umlauts in the path.

Comment: I have tested moving the document file out of my user account (it's in my Google Drive folder) and into a different directory ("C:\Test\Test"), but I got the same error message - the problem (or at least, the _first_ problem) seems to be where xindy.pl is located.

Comment: in your windows path, instead of `C:\Users\Jürgen\...` could you specify `c:\Users\ABCFGH~1\...` using whatever old msdos name `dir /x` reports for your directory?

Comment: Well it was worth a try. I can't run easily tests with such an installation directory so I can't check if it is the same problem or not.

Comment: I deinstalled MiKTeX and then reinstalled it as an admin. The xindy.pl file is now located here:

C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl

However, I am still the same error even though _no_ MikTeX-related files remain in the "C:\Users\Jürgen\" directory. I suspect the deinstallation wasn't quite clean, but I don't know where to look for this reference.

Comment: Further investigation: The C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\setup-2018-09-17-18-13.txt file (the log file for the setup) apparently lists my "C:\Users\Jürgen\" directory as the "Root0", "Root1", "UserInstall", "UserConfig", and "UserData" folders, even though I didn't specify those during the installation - this may be the cause of the problem. If I could prevent this from happening during installation or maybe modify it later, maybe it would work. You can see the file here:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rGgLk_pqhl3LW0Q35mxt3EKiB9asecaG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Another test - I get the same error when executing "texindy -V". The error seems to occur in line 865: "    system @command;". The actual "@command" that the script tries to execute is: --- C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/xindy/../../miktex/bin/x64/internal/xindy-lisp.exe -M C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/xindy/../../miktex/bin/x64/internal/xindy.mem -E iso-8859-1 "C:\\Test\\Test\\Lrxt3b2Kqf"

Comment: in a multiuser installation of miktex the data for the single users are in the user accounts.  That's normal. You can redirect the folders during installation: https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/miktexsetup.html. Did you try the suggestion of Stefan to redirect the user folder?

Comment: @David Carlisle: I vaguely remember that `xindy-lisp.exe` may not
support short names `ABCDEF~1`.
That was a reason that I changed the TMPDIR to be
the current directory.
There were cases in some machines that TEMP contains
a short name.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto hmm no unicode and no short names, that will make non ascii filenames difficult :(

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I've installed MiKTeX yet again with custom setup options, ensuring that the installation isn't anywhere near my C:/Users/Jürgen folder. I've even moved the setup executable away from my Downloads order. Yet I am still getting the same error:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PBW4kqyyWBtMwjmuTsMa99n7YnHqlDyE

Comment: Even when I start xindy-lisp.exe on its own _without_ any involvement of the xindy.pl script, it seems to refer to my User directory. Does anyone know where xindy-lisp.exe retrieves its configurations from?   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pstwF4b-4P_7fdL79RFaJV7BAm5Lv1kS

Comment: Or alternatively, does xindy-lisp.exe make use of any libraries (perhaps relevant to lisp) which might be located in the Users directories for some reason? I've noticed that "xindy-lisp.exe --help" works without any problems, for instance.

Comment: Here is a crashdump of xindy-lisp.exe, in case there is any relevant information in it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GfiQTinLpEiwfFzslzAHFPt9RLuE40Lx

Comment: @Jürgen Hubert: I don't know `CLISP`. But I looked over
`pathname.c` in `clisp`.
If the environment variable `HOME` is not
defined, `xindy_lisp.exe` tries to read
`HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` to know the current
home directory for the current user.
`%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` is `%USERPROFILE%`.
Thus `xindy_lisp.exe` tries to read your
name with a `non-ascii` character and fails.

I think that you can use `xindy` in the following way:

(1) Make a directory which does not include
    non-ascii characters. For example,
    `c:\Users\hubert`
(2) See the following comment.

Comment: (2) Define an environment variable `HOME`
    with the value `c:\Users\hubert`

Comment: Can this directory be empty, or does there need to be anything within it?

Comment: @Jürgen Hubert: It can be empty.

Comment: Okay, messing around with the HOMEPATH variable seems to have done the trick. I will do some further tests to ensure that it (a) really works and (b) I haven't messed up my system yet _again_, and then I will write up some lengthier details on what I did for future reference and criticism. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

To recap, the problem arose because the xindy_lisp.exe executable invoked by the xindy.pl script cannot cope with Umlauts (or presumably, other special characters) in file and directory names. This post a problem for me, since my username is "Jürgen" and thus many of my files and applications are located in my "C:\Users\Jürgen" folder

Furthermore, even after I removed both my MiKTeX installation and my test .tex file from the "C:\Users\Jürgen" file, the problem persisted. After following advice I had received here, I examined my environmental variables and discovered that both the HOMEPATH and LOCALAPPDATA made use of "\Users\Jürgen", and that xindy_lisp.exe somehow tried and failed to access either or both of these directories (even though there was nothing relevant there).

Thus, I needed to change these environmental variables. However, since I don't know what other software made use of these variables, I wanted the original directories to remain accessible. Thus, I decided to set a hard symbolic link. In the Windows Terminal:

```
mklink /J C:\User_Juergen C:\Users\Jürgen
```

This had the added benefit of making the .tex files in my Google Drive accessible to xindy-lisp.exe, since my Google Drive folder was also within my C:\Users\Jürgen hierarchy.

Thus, I set HOMEPATH="\User_Juergen" and LOCALAPPDATA="C:\User_Juergen\AppData\Local", and xindy-lisp.exe ceased to cause a problem.

Thanks to everyone who helped me figure this out!